# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not always working

Tags: android, facebook, sharedpreferences

I've got the following OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the OnCreate() method of my MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){
    @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){
        if (key.equals("session_open")) {
            signedIn = prefs.getBoolean("session_open", false);
            if (signedIn) {
                SlidingTabFragment fragment = new SlidingTabFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.spotview_content_fragment, fragment)
                        .commit();
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                drawerLearned = prefs.getBoolean("drawer_learned", false);
                if (!drawerLearned) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
            } else {
                MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.spotview_content_fragment, mainFragment)
                        .commit();
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            }
        }
    }
};
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

The prefs variable is initialized as `prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());` I also have a facebook login button in a fragment with the following OnSessionChanged method:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        editor.putBoolean("session_open", true);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        editor.putBoolean("session_open", false);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

with

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
editor = prefs.edit();
```

The idea is that whenever a user logs in or out using the fb-button, the SharedPreferences get updated and the listener picks up on this and changes the layout accordingly. However, this doesn't always seem to work. Most of the time it does work, but sometimes it suddenly stops working and I have to close the app and restart it to get it to work again. The SharedPreferences HAVE been changed then, since it opens with the corrent layout (there is also a check for the SharedPreferences in the OnCreate method which makes sure it loads the correct layout on startup). The listener just didn't pick up on it. Can someone please explain to me what's going wrong here and how I can fix this? If you need to see more of my code, please ask and I will post what you need. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){
    @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){
```

into

```
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
```

and changing listener into a private variable. I also added the following `@Override` functions:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }
```

Now it works every time.